# Angular Material stepper - override icons for dynamic steps

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this Angular Material stepper component where the steps are dynamically loaded. I want to customize icons for my steps instead of the default numbers. I am defining `ng-template` with an icon of my choice and adding a `state` attribute to my `mat-step`. Am I doing anything wrong with this syntax? I am still getting the default numbering.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [selectedIndex]=currentStep (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)" [linear]="true" labelPosition="bottom">

    <ng-template matStepperIcon="mail">
        <i class="fas fa-mailbox"></i>
    </ng-template>

    <mat-step [completed]="step.completed"  *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index"  [label]="step.name" state="step.state">
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
        <router-outlet  *ngIf="i === currentStep"></router-outlet>
    </mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

- 

```
 steps: IProposalStep[] = ProposalStatusesConst;
```

- 

```
export const ProposalStatusesConst: IProposalStep[] = [
    { name: 'Employer Basics', urlPath: 'employer-basics', state: 'mail', completed: false},
    { name: 'Employee Demographic', urlPath: 'employee-info', completed: false},
    // { name: 'Employee Coverage Lines', urlPath: 'coverage-lines' },
    { name: 'MHQ', urlPath: 'mhq', completed: false },
    { name: 'Products And Pricing', urlPath: 'products-and-pricing', completed: false },
    { name: 'Generate Proposal', urlPath: 'proposal-generation', completed: false }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could include state in your mat-step to replace the numbers with icons. So for example

<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" label="Enter your email" state="fas fa-mailbox">